# Algorithm to calculate parking fee based on certain rules

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate parking fee based on below rule.

- If a vehicle is parked for less than 0.5 hours, the fee will be $1
- If the vehicle is parked for more than 0.5 hours and less than 4 hours, the fee will be $2
- Maximum parking fee for 24 hours can be $6

Some example calculations:

```
For 10 minutes => $ 1
For 40 Minutes => $ 2
For 4.5 hours => $2 + $1
For 6 Hours => $2 + $2
For 16 Hours => $6
For 26 Hours => $6 + $2
```

I am storing the fee rule in a JS Array like this.

```
var rule = [{upto : 0.5, fee : 1}, {upto : 4, fee : 2}, {upto : 24, fee : 6}];
```

The rule can change in future. I want the algorithm in such a way that I have to only update the `rule` Array to apply the new fee rule.

I am using `Math.abs` and `Modulus %` operator together with iterations over the `rule` Array but none is giving me desired result. Could someone help me?

Comment: So many ways to do this, but personally I would probably do an  array map with hours or minutes as a key, and value as the fee. Then find the last/largest key that is smaller than your parking time, value giving you the fee.

Comment: Hi mate, can you post the code you have wrote till now ?

Comment: what will be the output if user put the value 8 hours ?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be not to use `switch` or multiple `if else` statements, but more declarative way:

```
rule.find(entry => hours < entry.upto).fee
```

In this case all you need is just to update an array of conditions and keep it in ascending order by `upto`. We even can skip ascending order if to use min and max values in array instead of `upto`.

```js
let rule = [{upto : 0.5, fee : 1}, {upto : 4, fee : 2}, {upto : 24, fee : 6}];
    console.log(getFee(rule, 3));
    
    function getFee(rule, hours) {
      if (!rule || rule.length === 0) return;
      let result = rule.find(entry => hours < entry.upto && entry.fee);
      return result.fee || 6 // found fee or max value
    }
    
    
// With min/max:
rule = [{min: 0, max : 0.5, fee : 1}, {min : 0.5, max : 4, fee : 2}, {min : 4, max : 24, fee : 6}];
console.log(getFeeWithMinMax(rule, 3));

    function getFeeWithMinMax(rule, hours) {
      if (!rule || rule.length === 0) return;
      let result = rule.find(entry => hours < entry.max && hours > entry.min);
      return result.fee || 6 // found fee or max value
    }
```

Comment: This will cause a TypeError in case there is not a rule with upto > hours

Comment: It is just a solution. We can use corner case checks for invalid data like you mentioned and some default values in case if 'rule' array is empty or does not contain enough big 'upto' value.

Comment: I'd give you the upvote if you included that code + showed also the skip ascending order version.

Answer (score 0):

```
total_days = total_hours / 24
total_cost = total_days * 6  (max cost 6 for every day/ 24hours)    
hours = total_days % 24 (remaining hours if any)    
if hours >= 8  and hours <= 24
total_cost += 6
else if hours >= 4 and hours <= 8
total_cost += 4
else if hours >= 0.5 and hours <= 4
total_cost += 2
else
total_cost += 1
```

> The way it approaches like in atm machines to find the number of maximum currency and then going from highest to lowest currency value.

total_cost will be the final fee
does it helps ..?

Answer (score 0):

This soulution features normalized times with *minutes*. This allows to use this unit for the calculation of the rest time without conversion.

I suggest to check the max count of a certain fee to avoid to high fees.

```js
function getFee(minutes) {
    return rules.reduceRight((sum, { upto, fee }, i, { [i + 1]: higher }) => {
        var count = Math[i ? 'floor' : 'ceil'](minutes / upto);
        if (higher && count * fee > higher.fee) {
            minutes = 0;
            return sum + higher.fee;
        }
        minutes = Math.max(0, minutes - upto * count);
        return sum + count * fee;
    }, 0);
}

var rules = [{ upto: 30, fee: 1 }, { upto: 240, fee: 2 }, { upto: 1440, fee: 6 }];

console.log(getFee(10));   // 1
console.log(getFee(40));   // 2
console.log(getFee(270));  // 2 + 1
console.log(getFee(360));  // 2 + 2
console.log(getFee(960));  // 6
console.log(getFee(1560)); // 6 + 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something simple like this:

```
var rule = [{upto : 0.5, fee : 1}, {upto : 4, fee : 2}, {upto : 24, fee : 6}]

function getFee(timeSpent) {
    var fee = rule[rule.length-1].fee;
    for (var i = rule.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (rule[i].upto >= timeSpent) {
            fee = rule[i].fee;
        }
    }
    return fee;
}
```